# C++ Initialization list with expressions

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor, code-formatting, initialization-list

I've just learned that I should be using an initialization list instead of assignments in my C++ constructors. Here is my example.

**Assignment Example: **

```
Class Graph {
private:
    int count;
    int spacing;
    int width;

public:
    Graph(int _count, int _spacing, int _chart_width) {
        count = _count;
        spacing = _spacing;
        width = (_chart_width - ((_count - 1) * _spacing)) / _count;
    }
};
```

**Initialization List Example: **

```
Class Graph {
private:
    int count;
    int spacing;
    int width;

public:
    Graph(int _count, int _spacing, int _chart_width) : count(_count), spacing(_spacing), width((_chart_width - ((_count - 1) * _spacing)) / _count) {}
};
```

As you can see, this looks really ugly.

My question is:

1. Is this the way to write an Initialization list constructor with expressions?
2. Is there a better syntax? What if the expression is really long and makes the Initialization list syntax completely unreadable?
3. Should I write a method `getWidth()` that computes the `width` and cleans up the constructor? Something like `width(getWidth(_chart_width))`.
4. Initialization list syntax indicates that, for example, `count(_count)` is a function that takes in `_count` as an input argument. Am I mixing up the Initialization list syntax with function syntax? or is `count()` truly a function? This is very confusing.
5. If the way I am writing the Initialization list is correct, can you please suggest a better way to format the code for readability? I guess, I would like to know what is the most common syntax for long Initialization lists.

Comment: use a helper function.

Comment: To follow up on that, when using a helper function for this purpose, you may as well make it a private static member function.

Comment: If you put everything on a single line in the first version, that would look ugly too

Comment: Downside of the member function, even a `private` `static` one, is now it's part of the interface, and probably inside a header, and that restricts your ability to tweak the parameters without forcing a recompile of everything.

Comment: @md5i, should I write a helper function `static int getWidth()`  as a method in the `Graph` class itself?

Comment: @Fermi It's a valid option.  But I would suggest a better name, such as `calculateInitialWidth()`, which better expresses its purpose.  But I will say that this particular calculation seems short enough that I don't really think you need a separate function for it.

Comment: @md5i Agreed, the sample I've given just an example. I am trying to imagine some complicated expression that would just make things look ugly and unreadable. Noted on the `calculateInitialWidth()` as a better name. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different projects (and people) have different coding standards and tastes, but personally I find this formatting very readable:

```
Class Graph {
  private:
    int count;
    int spacing;
    int width;

  public:
    Graph(int _count, int _spacing, int _chart_width)
        : count(_count), spacing(_spacing),
          width((_chart_width - ((_count - 1) * _spacing)) / _count)
    {}
};
```

And no, these are not necessarily function calls. But they can be... The best way to think about it is the following: if the variables you are initializing are instances of a class, then you are calling the constructor to initialize them. If you view it this way, the syntax makes sense.

And I would recommend a helper function (as a private and maybe static method of the class) for calculating the width.

Comment: "if the variables you are initializing are instances of a class." But variables are not instances of a class.

Comment: Imagine you had another class where the members aren't just ints, but maybe your new class had a member of type Graph. Then the initializer would call the constructor of Graph.

Comment: You're right - If the variables are objects, then it makes sense. But in the case of an `int`, the syntax is flawed in some ways. I am new to C++ with Java background and I've been scratching my head for a while.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the way to write an Initialization list constructor with expressions?

Yes, it is (although you could format it to be more readable).

> Is there a better syntax? What if the expression is really long and makes the Initialization list syntax completely unreadable?

Not that I am aware of. You can format the list in lines if it becomes too long. If your parameter's initialization is very long, complex and barely readable (i.e. takes 2-3 lines and is full of logic) I'd recommend moving it to the constructor's body. As a general rule of thumb, the initializer list is used to do just that: initialize. You shouldn't be doing blocks of logic in your list's parameters for a few reasons:

1. If your parameter requires a small math equation, that's fine, but anything more than that might require its own function. It could also be done in the object's constructor where you can use names variables to represent what is going on.
2. A general rule of "Clean Code" is to not try to be clever. If something isn't readable, you should make an active effort to make it understandable by your peers.
3. See answer to your next question.

> Should I write a method getWidth() that computes the width and cleans up the constructor? Something like width(getWidth(_chart_width)).

3. It's perfectly acceptable to use a function call in your initializer list's parameters. I'd even encourage you to do so for the sake of readability. At the end of the day, one of the initializer list's main function is to rid your constructor of "x = _x" lines that could fill it, and make some room for functions that aren't simply assigning values.

> Initialization list syntax indicates that, for example, count(_count) is a function that takes in _count as an input argument. Am I mixing up the Initialization list syntax with function syntax? or is count() truly a function? This is very confusing.

Basically, C++ is creating an implicit function to assign the passed parameters to the proper variable. Think of this as C++ creating a bunch of invisible functions that look like this:

```
aType setVarName(aType aParam)
{
    varName = aParam;
}
```

> If the way I am writing the Initialization list is correct, can you please suggest a better way to format the code for readability? I guess, I would like to know what is the most common syntax for long Initialization lists.

You initializer list should be at the same place you define your constructor. In the example you provided, your constructor is empty and so you decided to define it in your header file, so you can define the list there as well. I know this doesn't apply to your situation, but it's always good to keep in mind that if your constructor did have content, you should define the list just above the constructor's block in your ".cpp" file as such:

```
Graph(int _count, int _spacing, int _chart_width) : 
count(_count),
spacing(_spacing), 
width((_chart_width - ((_count - 1) * _spacing)) / _count) 
{
    ...
    [your constructor's code here]
    ...
}
```

I was taught that you should separate each parameter by a new line, but as rain city said: "Different projects (and people) have different coding standards and tastes".

Really though, I would advise against writing it all in one line regardless, as it severely hinders its readability if it becomes large. You'd generally want to avoid lines which would require "portrait monitor" users to have to scroll horizontally.

Edit: I noticed you said you had a background in java in another comment, and were wondering about the logic behind the int vs object. While I'm not sure if Java does this, C++ does a lot of implicit function definitions, where it will "silently" generate functions to accomplish some common behavior. For instance, objects can have an implicit copy constructor which allows you to create an instance of an object by passing it another object of the same type. In the initializer list's case, however, they're simply implicit functions that assign values to variables. I would recommend reading-up on the different cases of implicit functions in C++ to wrap your head around it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain. With regards to implicit functions, would you please recommend a good resource/book? C++ is an extremely daunting language.

Answer (score 0):

My question is:

1. Is this the way to write an Initialization list constructor with expressions?

Yes

2. Is there a better syntax? What if the expression is really long and makes the Initialization list syntax completely unreadable?

Use multiple lines and indenting when lines get long.

3. Should I write a method getWidth() that computes the width and cleans up the constructor? Something like width(getWidth(_chart_width)).

Yes, you can do that, but it cannot be an instance method of the same class since you have no "this" yet.

4. Initialization list syntax indicates that, for example, count(_count) is a function that takes in _count as an input argument. Am I mixing up the Initialization list syntax with function syntax? or is count() truly a function? This is very confusing.

The syntax is the same.  It is the placement in the code that identifies it as an initialization and not a function call (following the ':' character following the constructor signature).  No, count is not a function, it is simply a way of indicating, for x(y), to initialize x with y.  In C++, the same syntax can be used for different things, they are differentiated by the context around them.  You will find the x(y) syntax is used for other things in C++ (macros is one, casts is another, and superclass initialization is another).

5. If the way I am writing the Initialization list is correct, can you please suggest a better way to format the code for readability? I guess, I would like to know what is the most common syntax for long Initialization lists.

Just use more than one line.  New lines can be used anywhere you can have spaces.  When you used new lines, used additional indenting.  You can use a little creativity, or you can refer to coding standards documents for ideas.  This is nice:

```
Graph(int _count, int _spacing, int _chart_width) : 
    count(_count), 
    spacing(_spacing),
    width((_chart_width - (_count - 1) * _spacing) / _count) {}
```

or if there are many parameters, you can do:

```
Graph(int _count,
     int _spacing,
     int _chart_width) : 
        count(_count), 
        spacing(_spacing),
        width((_chart_width - (_count - 1) * _spacing) / _count) {}
```